# wordpress get_post_meta give only first value

Tags: functions

I made one custome post in that there is one *custom field* call **_as_roomname**.

I create total 5 custom post and I want to retrive all it's name but I get only first value.

```
function postlogo(){
global $post;
$counting = 1;
$count = 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'casino', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
$rPosts = new WP_Query($args);

while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post();?>
<h1><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), '_as_roomname', true);?> Review </h1><?php
$count = $count + 1;    
endwhile;
}
```

**Output**

```
Casino.com Review
Casino.com Review
Casino.com Review
Casino.com Review
Casino.com Review
```

I want this unique name from all post but it give me only first value. How will I get that I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You have the parameter of `get_post_meta` set to `true` which returns single result, set it to false or remove it completely.

```
 $dump_array = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), '_as_roomname')
 //check whats in the array
 var_dump($dump_array);

// or loop for output
foreach( $dump_array as $dump )
echo $dump;
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay
I had tried that but it's give the same Output

Comment: Setting it to false or empty returns an array, so you have to loop over it for output most likely using `foreach`, I edited my answer.

Comment: it's also not working. Now it show blank array. `array(0) { }`

Comment: Then is must be a another problem, if the array is empty, it's empty.